# How to exclude node_modules from WebStorm code analysis (named 'Problems' on the bottom-left corner)

Tags: typescript, compilation, webstorm, code-analysis, tsconfig

I am relying on this extensively on my workflow, but for some reasons this feature is now warning me of all the problems coming from `node_modules`, which obviously I'm not interested in.

[image]

How can I make WebStorm analyse my whole project problems without the `nodes_modules` folder?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? Excluding the node_modules directory doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

This is due to TSC itself reporting errors, and Project Errors within Webstorm just displays them. This is mentioned in the youtrack link below. I was able to remove all of my errors by adding the skipLibCheck option in tsconfig.json; however we decided not to enable that option at this time because if its side effects.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53460/Errors-from-nodemodules-in-type-script

Answer (score 0):

For me, node modules are excluded by default, but here's a useful tip when you don't want a directory to show up in JetBrains IDE's (WebStorm,PHP Storm,...):

Right click on your `node_modules` folder and select **Mark Directory as** > **Excluded**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ2Cj.png)